# How to solve this nonhomogeneous heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I don't know how to solve it
$$
 \left\lbrace \begin {array}{lcc} u_{t} \left( x,t \right) =u_{{\it xx}}
 \left( x,t \right) +2\,{{\rm e}^{-t}} \left( x-1+\sin \left( \pi\,x
 \right)  \right) &0<x<1&t>0\\ u \left( 0,t
 \right) =2\,{{\rm e}^{-t}}&t \geq 0 & \\u \left( 1
,t \right) =3&t \geq 0 & \\u \left( x,0 \right) =x+2
&0<x<1& \end {array}\right.$$

Comment: no in fact just expand $f(x) = x, x \in (0,1)$ as a Fourier series, and solve $u_t - u_{xx} = e^{-t+ 2 i \pi n x}$ (easy), then solve the homogeneous equation for the obtained boundary conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you could solve the PDe if it was homogeneous. So, first make it homogeneous. This requires to find a particular solution.

Search for a particular solution :

Taking account of the right term of the PDE, we search a solution on the form $2e^{-t}(ax+b+c\sin(\pi x))$ . Putting this function into the PDE, it is very easy to identify the coefficients : $a=-1 \:;\: b=1 \:;\: c=\frac{1}{\pi^2-1}$

A particular solution is $y=2e^{-t}\left(-x+1+\frac{1}{\pi^2-1}\sin(\pi x)\right)$

The change of function $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+2e^{-t}\left(-x+1+\frac{1}{\pi^2-1}\sin(\pi x)\right)$ leads to the homogeneous PDE :

$$
 \left\lbrace \begin {array}{lcc} v_{t} \left( x,t \right) =v_{{\it xx}}
 \left( x,t \right)
\\ v \left( 0,t\right) =0 
\\v \left( 1,t \right) =3 
\\v \left( x,0 \right) =3x-2\frac{1}{\pi^2-1}\sin(\pi x)
 \end {array}\right.$$
I suppose that you can continue from here.